# Change User boolean value after subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean, boolean-expression

I currently have Users with a Subcribed Boolean value set to False.

**How can i change the value once the User creates a subscription?**

I have written my code below....New to Rails please help :)

**MODELS**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :username, :email, :subscribed

  has_one :subscription, :dependent => :destroy

end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :plan_id, :user_id, :email

  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user

  after_create :subscribed

  def subscribed    ***This is my current code
    if self.user.subscribed == false
      self.user.subscribed = true
    end
  end

  def save_with_payment
    if valid?
      save_with_stripe_payment
    end
  end

  def save_with_stripe_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(card: stripe_card_token, email: email, plan: plan_id, description: "Unlimited Comics")
    self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
    save!
  rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
    logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
    false
  end

end
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])
    @subscription = plan.subscriptions.build
    @subscription.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :success => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

**SHEMA**

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.boolean  "subscribed",             :default => false    ***change to True
    t.string   "username"
  end

  create_table "subscriptions", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "plan_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

Comment: I can see security hole here. Malicious user can create subscription for someone else than  himself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
after_create :subscribed

def subscribed
  self.user.update_attribute(:subscribed, true) unless self.user.subscribed
end
```

Comment: you should rename it from `subscribed` to `subscribe`, `subscribed` is already an attribute

Comment: @AmolPujari `subscribe` is an attribute of the `user` and not of `subscription` and we are writing method in the `class Subscription`...so i think it will not create a problem.....though i agree with you method name must be meaningful like `update_user_subscribed`

Answer (score 2):

```
 def subscribed    ***This is my current code
    if self.user.subscribed == false
      self.user.subscribed = true
    end
  end

After self.user.subscribed = true add self.user.save
```

If you have mentioned the relation correctly